# Implement Basic Auth in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, basic-authentication, asp.net-core

I’m using ASP.NET Identity with Forms auth in an MVC6 application, and trying to implement Basic auth for the API endpoints.

I would have thought there’d be a pre-built middleware that does it, but haven’t been able to find it. I’ve had a look at the Filters test website https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/test/WebSites/FiltersWebSite and I can’t seem to work out what it’s doing/which parts are important.

I’ve tried using the pre-5 approach of manually doing basic auth in an authorizationfilter, but SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect seems to be gone, and the CookieAuthenticationHandler keeps redirecting to the login page.

Comment: To answer the 'pre-built middleware' question, “Basic auth does not meet [the katana team’s] security requirements” - https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/381

Comment: I suspect I’d need to subclass both `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` and `CookieAuthenticationHandler`, and reproduce all of logic hidden in `UseIdentity`, OR rewrite the `UseIdentity` helper to make Cookie auth passive, and manually redirect everywhere that’s needed?

Comment: Are you targeting a specific web host (e.g. IIS)

Comment: At the moment it’s deployed in IIS, but it kind of defeats the purpose of building an OWIN application by tying to a specific host.

Answer (score 2):

Basic auth is not there by design. Security team is against it. They will probably make a sample later.

you can read a discussion on the issue here : https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/209

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue @Bart. I can’t say I agree with the ‘let’s not implement this part of the HTTP spec because someone might use it wrong’ attitude, but I guess they have to do what makes them happy.

Comment: Third party option referenced at the bottom of the discussion: https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Odachi/blob/master/src/Odachi.Security.BasicAuthentication/BasicAuthenticationAppBuilderExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

Since you are targeting IIS, I suggest leveraging IIS for basic authentication.  You can drop a web.config file into your wwwroot folder with a section to configure your basic authentication options.

---

If you want to remain host agnostic, you will need middleware.  Here is someones implementation: https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Odachi/tree/master/src/Odachi.Security.BasicAuthentication

Comment: AFAIK IIS only supports Basic Auth against Windows accounts - I need to auth with ASP.NET Identity. At any rate, I can’t see this solving the redirects going on inside the OWIN middleware?

Comment: Yes, I’ve seen that one - see my comment on Bart’s answer. The real issue isn’t the basic auth (I have this working via a filter atm), it’s configuring/modifying the CookieAuthenticationHandler so it doesn't hijack the request/response.